# Add query string to url when redirect to 404 page

Tags: magento2, redirection

Please advice to add query string param to URL when magento2 redirect to 404 no-route page

for example here is no route path: magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/noroute I need to append query like ?test=001 after URL magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/noroute?test=001

I tried to use setParam in NoRouteHandler class but still, it is not working

Comment: Please share what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Vendor Name: Brazillion

Module Name: Pagenotfound

File: registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Brazillion_Pagenotfound',
    __DIR__
);
```

File:etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Brazillion_Pagenotfound" setup_version="1.0.0" />
</config>
```

File: etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlerClassesList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="brazillion_pagenotfound_pagenotfound" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Brazillion\Pagenotfound\App\Router\NoRouteHandler</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">45</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

File: etc\frontend\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="brazillian" frontName="brazillian">
            <module name="Brazillion_Pagenotfound"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

File: App\Router\NoRouteHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace Brazillion\Pagenotfound\App\Router;

use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class NoRouteHandler implements \Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandlerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $state;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
     */

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    )
    {
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function process(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        if($this->state->getAreaCode() == 'frontend' && !$request->getParam('test'))
        {
            $request->setModuleName('brazillian')->setControllerName('redirect')->setActionName('pagenotfound');
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

File: Controller\Redirect\Pagenotfound.php

```
<?php

namespace Brazillion\Pagenotfound\Controller\Redirect;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Pagenotfound extends Action
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     */

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $term = $this->_getTerm();
        $q = $this->getRequest()->getParam('test');
        if(!$q)
        {
            $this->_redirect($term, ['_query' => 'test=001']);
        }

    }

    protected function _getTerm()
    {
        $term = $this->getRequest()->getOriginalPathInfo();
        $term = trim($term, '/');
        $term = implode('/' , explode('/', $term));
        return $term;
    }
}
```

Thats it, it will work without changing anything.

Comment: I assume, you want to redirect to custom page from 404 page with a query string !!! If not let me know exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: i just need to add query string param in url when page return 404 not found page.

Comment: i already try to ->setParam in NoRouteHandler process method but anything not change

Comment: for example here is no route path : http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/noroute i need to append query like ?test=001 after url 
http://magento2demo.firebearstudio.com/noroute?test=001

Comment: Edited answer with the changes. Try and let me know if you still need anymore help !!

Comment: what is frontend_slug

Comment: frontend_slug is the key you defined for your module in etc\frontend\routes.xml file

Comment: Edited answer with exact extension. Try that and let me know if it works !!

Comment: thx u so much , please reupload file routes.xml

Comment: Done, updated. Please check.

Comment: Add it as accepted answer would be appreciated if it worked.

Comment: found  issue when disable product and go to product page (by direct url) error too many redirect

Comment: I dont think this is related to this extension, it must be something else. As for the first time it appends test querystring, now for the second time, the condition will not fulfil as it is already having test querystring so this should not come into picture. Check one more time to be sure if this is causing issue because of this functionality or not. Probably by disabling this extension ..